# getString from Bundle loses old value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

From FirstActivity I'm creating three seperate Notifications and on clicking them I start SecondActivity which is in the same application. The issue is the value of the string in the SecondActivity is always the last Notification which i posted. I need to start SecondActivity and display call is from Notification 1 when i click on Notification with id =1 and similarly for id = 2 and id =3. But I'm losing those put extras in my intent object. Please help me with this if you have come across such a situation before. I've tried PendingIntent flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT but in vain. Thanks in advance. :-)

```
NotificationManager nm;
Notification n;
PendingIntent pi1, pi2, pi3;
Button btnNotify1, btnNotify2, btnNotify3;
Intent intent;

final static String TICKER_TEXT = "My_Notification";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    btnNotify1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotify1);
    btnNotify2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotify2);
    btnNotify3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotify3);

    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, TICKER_TEXT,
        System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.flags = n.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    btnNotify1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("call_is_from", "Notification 1");
            pi1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Notification 1",
                "One", pi1);
            nm.notify(1, n);

        }
    });
    btnNotify2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("call_is_from", "Notification 2");
            pi2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Notification 2",
                "Two", pi2);
            nm.notify(2, n);

        }
    });
    btnNotify3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("call_is_from", "Notification 3");
            pi3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Notification 3",
                "Three", pi3);
            nm.notify(3, n);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that each of your `PendingIntent`s is unique. Since you are getting a `PendingIntent` using the same `Intent` and the same `requestCode`, you will always get the same `PendingIntent` (even though the extras are different).

To make sure that each of your `PendingIntent`s is unique, use a different `requestCode` for each, like this:

```
pi1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

pi2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 2,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

pi3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 3,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```